# traefik portainer swarm 404

Tags: docker-swarm, traefik, portainer

when i try to reach endpoint for portainer or traefik i get 404 not found  error.

It's work well if i setup in docker and not docker swarm. I believe i miss config something like balancer.

something i miss with thetraefik.http.services.<service_name>.loadbalancer.server.port

**Without swarm config:**

```
# traefik.yml

api:
  dashboard: true

entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
  https:
    address: ":443"

providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false

certificatesResolvers:
  http:
    acme:
      email: kevin.gaulin@gmail.com
      storage: acme.json
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: http
```

---

```
#docker-compose.yml

version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.3.7
    container_name: traefik
    restart: unless-stopped
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    networks:
      - traefik-proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro
      - ./acme.json:/acme.json
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik2.${DOMAIN}`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=${USERNAME}:${HASHED_PASSWORD}"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-https-redirect"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.rule=Host(`traefik2.${DOMAIN}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.middlewares=traefik-auth"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.certresolver=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.service=api@internal"

  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer-ce:latest
    container_name: portainer
    restart: unless-stopped
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    networks:
      - traefik-proxy
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./portainer-data:/data
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.rule=Host(`portainer2.${DOMAIN}`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.portainer-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.middlewares=portainer-https-redirect"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.rule=Host(`portainer2.${DOMAIN}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.tls.certresolver=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.service=portainer"
      - "traefik.http.services.portainer.loadbalancer.server.port=9000"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik-proxy"

networks:
  traefik-proxy:
    external: true
```

**Swarm config**

```
# traefik.yml

api:
  dashboard: true

entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
  https:
    address: ":443"

providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
    swarmmode: true
    watch: false

certificatesResolvers:
  http:
    acme:
      email: kevin.gaulin@gmail.com
      storage: acme.json
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: http
log:
  level: DEBUG
```

---

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.3.7
    networks:
      - traefik-proxy
    ports:
       - 80:80
       - 443:443

    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro
      - ./acme.json:/acme.json
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=http"
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik2.${DOMAIN}`)"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=${USERNAME}:${HASHED_PASSWORD}"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-https-redirect"
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.entrypoints=https"
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.rule=Host(`traefik2.${DOMAIN}`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.middlewares=traefik-auth"
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.certresolver=http"
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.service=api@internal"
        - "traefik.http.services.traefik.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"

  agent:
    image: portainer/agent
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes:/var/lib/docker/volumes
    networks:
      - agent_network
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints: [node.platform.os == linux]


  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer-ce:latest
    command: -H tcp://tasks.agent:9001 --tlsskipverify
    networks:
      - traefik-proxy
      - agent_network
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - ./portainer-data:/data
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.entrypoints=http"
        - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.rule=Host(`portainer2.${DOMAIN}`)"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.portainer-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
        - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.middlewares=portainer-https-redirect"
        - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.entrypoints=https"
        - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.rule=Host(`portainer2.${DOMAIN}`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.tls=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.tls.certresolver=http"
        - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.service=portainer"
        - "traefik.http.services.portainer.loadbalancer.server.port=9000"
        - "traefik.docker.network=traefik-proxy"

networks:
  traefik-proxy:
    driver: overlay
    external: true
  agent_network:
    driver: overlay
```